# Preview de documentos con angular

Tags: html, angular

estoy intentando hacer un preview de un documento con angular, actualmente estoy usando serve, para servir una carpeta con mis archivos. y la libreria ngx-doc.viewer para renderizar mis documentos

el Código que estoy usando es el siguiente. este me funciona si le paso una ruta quemada, pero no me funciona cuando lo hago con mi carpeta servida en localhost

```html
<div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <ngx-doc-viewer 
            [url]="'http://localhost:3000/'+selectedFile.source"
            viewer="google"
            style="width:100%;height:50vh;">
            </ngx-doc-viewer>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Al ejecutar este codigo en mi aplicación, en la sección de network me aparece que me carga un documento, mas sin embargo no me realiza el preview. Muchas gracias por tomar el tiempo de leer hasta aqui, esperando que me puedan ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA:** {{selectedFile.source}} me indica la ruta del archivo seleccionado, y esta ruta está establecida en mi base de datos

Comment: Alguno tiene una idea de como hacerlo? :'c

Answer (score 0):

yo no he tenido éxito con esa librería, ya que no pre visualiza archivos y la documentación no me ha sido de ayuda, pero la solución encontrada para archivos **OFFICE** es la de usar en la url de un iframe la api de google, donde ***http://docs.google.com/gview?url=*** es la api de visualización de archivos de google, ***&embedded=true*** permite incrustar el archivo en tu sitio web.
No te funcionará si tu archivo está en un servidor local.

```html
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=(aquí colocas la url de tu archivo que debe estár publicado en la red)&embedded=true"></iframe>
```